Delphi 12.1 and FastReport from GetIt
i'm using Delphi 12.1 and i installed the Fastreport from/with GetIt.
The process didn' succeed, some error about the package: dclfrxTee29.bpl.
I didn't install teechart components during Delphi setup.
I can see why it might pose a problem, but all other packages were installed successfuly.
One thing is missing, the FastReport Wizards on the File/New menu.
I saw that it is possible to add stuff to the templates, any idea how to add the Wizards to it?
Tia
Laurent
